# Doubts about how to migrate WordPress from local to online server using Search and Replace Tool script

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I am trying to migrate my blog from my local web server to an online web server and I have a doubt about this procedure.

I have uploaded all my local file in the root of my web server.

I have also export the tables of my local database (using phpMyAdmin) and I have import them on my online database.

Then I have change the settings inside the file **wp-config.php** in such a way as to make the connection with the online database.

Now I have to change the URL settings on my database using the **Search and Replace Tool** script: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

So my doubts related to the use of the search and replace script are:

1) Have I to put the **searchreplacedb2.php** file into the root of my webserver (where it is the wp-config.php file) and have I to execute this script?

2) Have I to scann ALL the tables or only the posts table?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the script you have suggested , but what I always use is direct mysql queries like so :

```
/**
To update WordPress options with the new blog location, use the following SQL command:
**/

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

/**
After that you will need to fix URLs of the WordPress posts and pages, which translated from post slug, and stored in database wp_posts table as guid field. The URL values in this field are stored as abolute URLs instead of relative URLs, so it needs to be changed with the following SQL query:
**/

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');

/**
If you have linked internally within blog posts or pages with absolute URLs, these links will point to wrong locations after you move the blog location. Use the following SQL commands to fix all internal links to own blog in all WordPress posts and pages:
**/

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Note : something might have changed in the wp DB structure since I wrote this script , so just in case , after using it , goto `wp_options` table and double check the HOME and BLOG url entries to see they martch your new domain ..

Answer (score 0):

A safer alternative may be to leverage [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/), specifically its [search-replace](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) function.

You can perform this operation to a local copy of the database, then upload that to your production environment.